# How to access information in a javascript file that was send from a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, submit

I have this following code:

```
<form action="main.js">
        <input type="text" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

When i click the submit button, the information that was in the input should be sent to my file "main.js". But there is nothing in "main.js". I want that "main.js" file would contain that passed information as a string, is there a way or method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've understood `form action` incorrectly.

Action defines which code will handle your form values, and not which page will the results be pasted into.

you'll want main.js to receive the form results and handle them in a way to be pasted into a results.txt file for example. But allowing a user of your website to create or edit files on your server is insecure.

The only option i think of, unless you have access to server side coding, like php or asp, is sending the submitted form information to your email using mailto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

can you run asp or php?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, my new code looks like this now: <form action="main.js">
        <input class="inputField" type="text" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
        <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".myButton").on("click", function () {
                var value = $(".inputField").val();
                
            });
        });
    </script> Do you have some ideas how could i send now the value  information to the main.js file?

Comment: I dont think that i could that do with an ajax() method, is there some way to send it?

Answer (score -1):

Following could be the part of your `javascript` file.. If you are not going to include any JS file then you can use it directly.

```
function checkAge() {
    var x = document.forms["Form1"]["Age"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Age is empty");
        return false;
    }
    else
    alert(x);
}
```

Then your form should looks like

```
<form name="Form1" action="abc.jsp" onsubmit="return checkAge()" method="post">
Age: <input type="text" name="Age">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Cross check with your form and see what went wrong..

Comment: This does not answer the question.. His problem has no relation with field validations